# org.springframework.security.config package is missing

Tags: java, gradle, spring-security

I am building a web app with spring security and following along with a tutorial, but have ran in to a road block because the package `org.springframework.security.config` seems to be missing. I am using `spring-core-4.1.4` and `spring-security-4.1.1`.

Here are my dependencies in `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
     compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.1.1.RELEASE'
     compile 'org.springframework.security.kerberos:spring-security-kerberos-web:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

All of the other packages and classes I have seen in the tutorial are there, but the config package is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security have been cut into several modules, one of them being the Config Module.

You'll need to include that as well in your Gradle config.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Interesting. You'd think they would clearly mention that on the website where they give you the gradle path!

Comment: I cannot find it in the Grails repository. The `spring-security-core` package is there, but `config` is not. Why is that and how to solve it, please? I need the version for Grails 3.

Comment: OK, got it. I don't understand why, but the `core` plugin is under the `org.grails.plugins` namespace (`org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core`), but the `config` plugin is under the `org.springframework` namespace (`org.springframework.security:spring-security-config`).